# c++ void function as parameter for other function

Tags: c++, function, arguments, void

I do not understand why this code that uses int functions and parameters works correctly, but this other code with void functions and without parameters does not:

First:

```
#include <iostream>
int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int operation(int x, int y, int (*function)(int, int))
{
    return function(x, y);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << operation(1, 4, &Add) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Second:

```
#include <iostream>
void a()
{
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
}
void b(void (*function))
{
   function();
}
int main()
{
    b(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you should not need to take the address of Add(). Passing a function by name, without parameters, will automatically take the address.

```
std::cout << operation(1, 4, Add) << std::endl;
```

In your second example, you have forgotten the brackets in the function pointer:

```
void b(void (*function)(/* these brackets were missing */))
{
```

You also don't need to take the address of a when passing to b, because referring to a function without the parameters takes its address:

```
int main()
{
    b(a);
    return 0;
}
```